# Selenium Web Driver - Trying to Click on Save Button that has unselectable="on". Is there a way to get around this?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I am in the process of completing a script for work. The last step in my script is to click on the save button. I've tried several different methods(locate by id, css, and  xpath). I keep getting error messages from Jupyter " Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (908, 508)".

I am thinking it is due to the button having unselectable = "on". Does anyone know how to get around this?

Below is the HTML for the save button I am trying to click on.

[image: save button html]

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working on normal click.try the below code and check if it works for you.

```
element_btn=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.x-btn")   
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_btn)
```